# WinUI 3 "XAML parsing failed." when adding MenuBar

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I'm experimenting with WinUI 3 and trying to create a basic user interface.

As soon as I add a `MenuBar` control, I get a `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException`: 'XAML parsing failed.' at the `InitializeComponent()` line of that view's code-behind when trying to start the app.

I can add other controls without issues, but `MenuBar` always seems to break the app. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `App.xaml` to include the `<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />` resource dictionary like this:

```xml
<Application
  x:Class="Your.Project.App"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <!-- the following line is important -->
         <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```